# Sencha IPAddress Field with dot as separator in between

Tags: extjs

I want to build a IP Address Field which will contain . as separator in between which is like the one which we configure in Internet Options in IE.I need to know whether there are any built in code available if not please guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: See this other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124043/form-field-for-ip-address-v4-with-extjs)